# Markdown not finding params when knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I try to knit the following document

````
----
title: "jerHW52"
output: html_document
params:
  missiontype: "Successful.Unmanned"
---

```{r warning=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
Launch_Data<-read.csv("NASA_Launch_Data.csv",header=TRUE)
NASA_Launch_Data<- Launch_Data %>% filter(Launch_Data$Type==params$missiontype)
ggplot(NASA_Launch_Data, aes(x=Year, y=Missions)) + geom_line() 
```
````

I get the following error

> Error in filter(., Launch_Data$Type == params$missiontype) : object
>   'params' not found Calls:  ... _fseq -> freduce ->
>   withVisible ->  -> filter Execution halted

Why would it not be able to find params?

Here is the start of the data in NASA_Launch_Data.csv

```
"","Year","Type","Missions"
"1",1957,"Successful.Unmanned",3
"2",1958,"Successful.Unmanned",28
"3",1959,"Successful.Unmanned",23
"4",1960,"Successful.Unmanned",40
"5",1961,"Successful.Unmanned",48
"6",1962,"Successful.Unmanned",76
"7",1963,"Successful.Unmanned",67
"8",1964,"Successful.Unmanned",99
"9",1965,"Successful.Unmanned",119
"10",1966,"Successful.Unmanned",129
```

Comment: It would be useful to see some example data from `NASA_Launch_Data.csv`. But it looks like you are using `filter` incorrectly and as the message says, there is simply no object named `params`. If there's a column named `Type` just use that name, not `Launch_Data$Type`. Are there columns named `params` or `missiontype`?

Comment: params should refer to the parameters passed to the markdown document in the header, no?  so params$missiontype should be "Successful.Unmanned" unless you have chosen "Knit with parameters" in R Studio (or changed it on the console command line, but I'm using R STudio) and changed it....

Comment: Right, I missed that usage of `params` first time around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that I'm an idiot....

Note the YAML header at the top of my document

```
----
title: "jerHW52"
output: html_document
params:
  missiontype: "Successful.Unmanned"
---
```

There are four dashes on the first line, not three as there should be.  Remove one and everything works...